# how to call CI models function by using varaibles

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had an array that has all the extensions' names, and I want to load the corresponding model for that extension, then call the install method. It should look something like this:

```
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $this->load->model('Model_'. $extension);
    $this->model_$extension->install(); //how do I achieve this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign model name to variable then use that variable to load model

```
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $load_model = 'Model_'. $extension;
    $this->load->model($load_model);        
    $this->$load_model->install(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $model = 'Model_'. $extension; // save in separate var
    $this->load->model($model);
    $this->$model->install(); 
}
```

I have tried but can not concatenate and assign at same time, so can have different variable and call.

Comment: Just beware that if you do reference these models elsewhere you need to stick to the Case as defined above... As the above is Model_xxx you would  need to use $this->Model_xxx->method(); If you use model_ to build the model string name - you can use lowercase $this->model_xxx->method();

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thanks for mentioning this. I have used lowercase in my code, just pasted code from question..

Comment: @JigarShah Yeah, you and B. Desai both answered this correctly. Since B. Desai answered a little bit earlier than you, I marked him as the correct.

Comment: Np , but let me tell the previous answer of B.Desai was different, optimized  after my answer.